# QuickBlox - Calling User / Creating Session from Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, quickblox

In my app, when the user hits the "Active" button and sends the app to the background, a jingle will play while the app periodically checks for other available users in the background.

If an available user is found, the user hears a ping and a call should start.

However, I'm unable to create QBRTCSessions while the app is running in the background. I use the code below:

```
QBRTCSession *session = [QBRTCClient.instance createNewSessionWithOpponents:opponentsIDs withConferenceType:QBConferenceTypeVideo];


if (session) {

    self.sessionQBRTC = session;
    [session startCall:nil];

} else {

     [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Creating new session - Failure"];

}
```

Where 'opponenetsIDs' is the ID of the available user found while in the background. However, I am getting the "Creating new session - Failure" error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot set the app permissions in "Capabilities" tab "Background Modes" and set the "Audio and AirPlay". Please check [background mode](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios#Background_mode)

I have tested your code [here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/QBRTCChatSample) and it works fine

Comment: second link is expired,can you please update if you know ?